# How in Ruby on Rails 4.2.6 make a statement which has to check for file extension and upload to right public folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload

I'm working on an application which has an upload functionality for documents. I can download various kind of documents like pdf, docx and etc.  However, all is uploaded in one folder like `../uploads/documents`. 
What I have to reach is when the upload began, a statement will check the file extension and upload it to the right folder named as the extension of the file. As an example, I can have a PDF in upload and the app check if the PDF directory exists and if not create one, then upload to that directory. So far I have done what below but I'm new in RoR so I would like to have some suggestions how to make what mentioned above:

This comes from my CTRL:

```
module UploaderWidget
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
  end

  def initialize(params = {})
    @file = params.delete(:file)
    super
    if @file
      self.filename = sanitize_filename(@file.original_filename)
      self.content_type = @file.content_type
      self.file_contents = @file.read
    end
  end

  def upload_local
    path = "#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/document"
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(path) unless File.exists?(path)
    FileUtils.copy(@file.tempfile, path)
  end

  private

  def sanitize_filename(filename)
    return File.basename(filename)
  end

  def document_file_format
    unless ["application/pdf","application/vnd.ms-excel",     
             "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
             "application/msword", 
             "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", 
             "text/plain", "text/csv", "application/octet-stream"].include? self.content_type
      errors.add(:file, 'Invalid file format.')
    end
  end

  NUM_BYTES_IN_MEGABYTE = 1048576
  def file_size_under_one_mb
    if (@file.size.to_f / NUM_BYTES_IN_MEGABYTE) > 1
      errors.add(:file, 'File size cannot be over one megabyte.')
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [File.extname()](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/File.html#extname-method) method:

> ```
> File.extname("test.rb")         #=> ".rb"
> File.extname("a/b/d/test.rb")   #=> ".rb"
> File.extname("foo.")            #=> ""
> File.extname("test")            #=> ""
> File.extname(".profile")        #=> ""
> File.extname(".profile.sh")     #=> ".sh"
> ```

In your particular case, you could do something like this:

- sanitize the file name and save it to an instance variable
- extract the extension name and save it to an instance variable
- eventually manipulate your extension name, e.g.

  - remove the '.' char
  - create an hash having every extension as a key and the sub-folder name as a value
  - define a method to manipulate the extension and return the folder name
- build your path like `path = Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', 'document' sub_folder_name)`

The rest of your code should work as it is